# PHP make some of the Key to be sticky in an Associative array

Tags: php

I try to use `array_column` and `array_multisort` to sort Array B by Key (ID).

However, I have a scenario whereby I need to have **some ID to be sticky on the top** .

For example,  by **comparing Array A and Array B**, move ID 3 and ID 1 to the top of the Array B. **The final result will be Array C** .

Is there a PHP array function to achieve this? Please advice...

**Array A**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1
        )
)
1
```

**Array B**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [product] => A
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [product] => B
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 3
            [product] => C
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 4
            [product] => D
        )
)
1
```

**Array C (Result)**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 3
            [product] => C
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [product] => A
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [product] => B
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 4
            [product] => D
        )
)
1
```

Comment: Do you mean all keys of array A should on top in the final result?

Comment: @d.coder yes correct

Comment: Will ID in Array B be unique?

Comment: @KarolGasienica yes, it's unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preparatory steps involved in generating the lookup and outlier values may be avoidable with more intimate knowledge of your project scope, but I'll only use the values that you have provided.  (I mean, you *could* hardcode outlier as `9999999` and wrap `array_flip` around `array_column` for brevity.)

The max value simply needs to be a value higher than the highest ID in the priority array.

The lookup needs to have ID values as keys and their original indexes as the new values (hence the flip).

`usort()` is precisely the php function to use when performing a custom sorting process.

`use` is necessary to pass the required additional values into the custom function's scope.

The spaceship operator (`<=>`) is a fantastic way to package your two-condition sort logic.  Each side will be compared using the values "left to right".

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/U8ao9))

```
$priority = [['ID' => 3], ['ID' => 1]];
$input = [['ID' => 1, 'product' => 'A'], ['ID' => 2, 'product' => 'B'], ['ID' => 3, 'product' => 'C'], ['ID' => 4, 'product' => 'D']];

$lookup = array_column($priority, 'ID');
$outlier = max($lookup) + 1;
$lookup = array_flip($lookup);

usort($input, function($a, $b) use ($lookup, $outlier) {
    return [$lookup[$a['ID']] ?? $outlier, $a['ID']] <=> [$lookup[$b['ID']] ?? $outlier, $b['ID']];
});

var_export($input);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'ID' => 3,
    'product' => 'C',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'ID' => 1,
    'product' => 'A',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'ID' => 2,
    'product' => 'B',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'ID' => 4,
    'product' => 'D',
  ),
)
```

Without the spaceship operator, the custom function gets noticeably more verbose.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/4eLm1))

```
usort($input, function($a, $b) use ($lookup, $outlier) {
    $bIsPriority = isset($lookup[$b['ID']]);
    if (isset($lookup[$a['ID']])) {
        if ($bIsPriority) {
            return $lookup[$a['ID']] - $lookup[$b['ID']];
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    } elseif ($bIsPriority) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return $a['ID'] - $b['ID'];
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm using several "tricks" in this one.  If you would like me to clarify a particular aspect, just ask.

Comment: You should not be using a sub-7 version.  The spaceship operator is not available in php 5.  I'll need to write a much longer custom function.  I'll edit when I can.  What php version are you using?

Comment: @gosulove I think I have the old skool version working for you.  If something isn't quite right, please offer the input that breaks my code and I'll adjust.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of doing it:

```
<?php
$a = [['ID' => 5], ['ID' => 1]];
$b = [['ID' => 1, 'product' => 'A'], ['ID' => 2, 'product' => 'B'], ['ID' => 3, 'product' => 'C'], ['ID' => 4, 'product' => 'D'], ['ID' => 5, 'product' => 'E']];

// $keysOnTop = Array([0] => 5, [1] => 1)
$keysOnTop = array_column($a, 'ID');

$temp1 = $temp2 = [];
foreach($b as $value){
    if(in_array($value['ID'], $keysOnTop)){
        $temp1[] = $value;
    } else {
        $temp2[] = $value;
    }
}
// $temp1 = Array([0] => Array([ID] => 1, [product] => A), [1] => Array([ID] => 5, [product] => E))
// $temp2 = Array([0] => Array([ID] => 2, [product] => B), [1] => Array([ID] => 3, [product] => C), [2] => Array([ID] => 4, [product] => D))

$final_arr = array_merge($temp1, $temp2);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($final_arr);

// Output:
/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [product] => A
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 5
            [product] => E
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [product] => B
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 3
            [product] => C
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 4
            [product] => D
        )

)
*/

?>
```

Comment: I expected 5 to be before 1 in the output.  See how the OP's array A relates to array C?  I think your process needs fixing.  All answers should include an explanation.

Comment: @d.coder thank you for your effort... However, the output is not the result that I expected... please check

Comment: @gosulove please do not upvote incorrect answers that will only confuse researchers.

Comment: I have only changed the input arrays only to check the validity of output. If you'll use your input array as specified in your question then it will produce the same expected output. How it is different?

Comment: @d.coder sorry! my mistake didn't see it carefully. Your coding works as well. Once again, thank you for your help