# How to sort an array in PHP while ensuring that a particular key remains at the top of the sorted list?

Tags: php, arrays

Following is the array that I want to sort:

```
// Sample array
$myArray = array(
    "apple" => 2,
    "orange" => 5,
    "banana" => 3,
    "kiwi" => 1,
);
```

The key that I want to keep on top is:

```
$specialKey = "banana";
```

Comment: Do you want to sort it by keys or by values ?

Comment: Related page processing 2d array: [PHP make some of the Key to be sticky in an Associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56230671/2943403).  Another related page: [Sorting PHP array by value then key by custom order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68483657/2943403)

Comment: See my answer from the 5 years ago which demonstrates how to key sort and array with a sticky key: [`uksort($myArray, fn($a, $b) => [$a !== $specialKey, $a] <=> [$b !== $specialKey, $b]);`](https://3v4l.org/enteO)

Answer (score 2):

I can see that you want to sort keys, so here is a shorter way to do the same (as well as performance wise faster):

```
<?php

// Sample array
$myArray = array(
    "apple" => 2,
    "orange" => 5,
    "banana" => 3,
    "kiwi" => 1,
);

$specialKey = "banana";
$toparray[$specialKey] = $myArray[$specialKey]; //get key-values in new array
unset($myArray[$specialKey]);//unset key-value from original array
ksort($myArray); //sort original array based on key
print_r($toparray+$myArray);//combine both array to get desired result
```

https://3v4l.org/atKpR

Comment: Please close duplicate questions instead of answering them.